# CreateIndex in Nest / Elastic Search 2.x after upgrade from 1.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I upgraded my Nest and Elastic Search NuGet packages to 2.4.6 from 1.7.1.  Everything seems to be working ok, but one thing I'm wary of is where I create the index.

There were two settings that I used to set in the old 1.x world that I couldn't figure out how to set in the 2.x world.  Creating an index went from this:

```
ixSettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
ixSettings.NumberOfShards = 5;
ixSettings.Settings.Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10");
ixSettings.Settings.Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s");

EsClient.CreateIndex(c => c
    .Index(ES_Index)
    .InitializeUsing(ixSettings)
);
```

to this:

```
EsClient.CreateIndex(ES_Index, c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfReplicas(1)
        .NumberOfShards(5)));

var mapResponse = EsClient.Map<WebPage>(m => m.AutoMap()); //apply the index mapping
```

I think the merge policy and fetch warn settings were something I got from an Elastic Search "Getting Started Guide".  The "merge_factor" defaults to 10, so that doesn't matter, and I guess the "search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn" is a logging thing.

My questions are:

1. Am I ok leaving those off my index creation in my new code?
2. How do I set them if I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings upon index creation have been improved to provide a fluent API and Object Initializer syntax for the settings that are allowed at index creation time.

You can set any key/value with `.Setting()`

```cs
client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfReplicas(1)
        .NumberOfShards(5)
        .Setting("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
        .Setting("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
    )
);
```

**But it should be noted** that [`merge.policy.merge_factor` is removed from Elasticsearch 2.0+](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_merge_and_merge_throttling_settings). You can find the settings that are supported on

```cs
client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfReplicas(1)
        .NumberOfShards(5)
        .Merge(m => m
            .Policy(mp => mp
                . // See which settings are available here
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Similarly, `search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn` can be set with

```cs
client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfReplicas(1)
        .NumberOfShards(5)
        .SlowLog(sl => sl
            .Search(ssl => ssl
                .Fetch(f => f
                    .ThresholdWarn("1s")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which produces the following request:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/index-name 
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn": "1s",
    "index.number_of_shards": 5
  }
}
```